# Monitoring OpenMQ in SCOM via JMX

Tags: scom, jmx

Is there a way to connect SCOM to OpenMQ via JMX to monitor it? I've found an app named BridgeWays Java Attributes that can apparently do this but it is right now in beta. I was wondering if SCOM has any built-in features for connecting to JMX though.